# IE9 Selectbox onchange Event doesnt fire correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-9, onchange

I have a normal `Selectbox`

```
<select id="areaSelectBox" onchange="javascript:checklistObj.CreateAreaFields(this)">
```

`checklistObj` is a object oriented prototype class with the function `CreateAreaFields`.

```
Debug: Script block [dynmaic] Runtime Error in JScript. This Object doesn't support this Method... (Break, Continue, Ignore)...
```

Please help.

Comment: ie9 does not fire the event onchange, y?... Firefox, Safari, does it.

Answer (score 1):

onchange works fine for me in ie9. something is wrong with your function.

```
<select onchange="javascript:alert('test')">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In Firefox, Safari the function is correct. hmm... i will check this again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found that this did not work in IE9 if the option in

`"Tools" --> "Compatibility View Settings" --> "Display all websites in Compatibility View"`
 or 
`"Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"` was selected. Once I removed these it worked fine. I discovered this by using the **"Developer Tools"** that come with IE9. Press **F12** to open Developer Tools and watch the "Console" tab for errors.